# Sending a command to screen in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04

In order to run a data analysis program, installed on a Teensy 2.0 microcontroller running arduino, I have to go to the screen by typing

`screen -S trans -L /dev/ttyACM0 (the name of the screen is trans).`

Once in the new screen, I have to enter 's' to start the scanning process. 
I am trying to write a script to automate the process of writing commands, but cannot figure out how to pass 's' into the screen to automatically begin the scanning process. 
I have tried commands such as

`screen -S trans -X stuff "s$(printf \\r)"`

`echo "s" > /dev/ttyACM0`

I'm working on a Linux Ubuntu OS.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is

```
screen -S trans -X stuff 'command'$(echo -ne '\015')
```

i.e

```
screen -S trans -X stuff 's'$(echo -ne '\015')
```

in your case. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you, but no. It goes to the screen but it doesn't input the 's'. Also just out of curiosity, what is '/015'/.

Comment: UPDATE: it works. Thank you so much. Now, can I please know how it works?

Comment: the \015 is carrier return '\r' can be used instead of the octal 015 if you like. Glad it's working, why didn't it work before?

Comment: I had manually detach and attach to the screen for the script to run and execute the command you mentioned.  But I don't know how to write it so not to worry about detaching and reattaching.

Comment: To be more specific, the script only runs in bash, and I need it to run in screen as well as in bash. Is that possible?

Comment: Don't think that's possible if you plan on sending commands to it.